# undefined method define_enum_for for RSpec::ExampleGroups

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, shoulda

I am getting `undefined define_enum_for method error` after upgrading rails to 4.2.0 from 4.1.

Is there any fix for this?

Rails : 4.2.0

Ruby : ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i686-linux]

```
  1) Recording 
     Failure/Error:
       should define_enum_for(:state).
         with({
           initial: 'initial',
           running: 'running',
           stopped: 'stopped'
         })

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `define_enum_for' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Recording:0x99a0ea8>
```

[shoulda-matchers#define_enum_for](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/Shoulda%2FMatchers%2FActiveRecord%3Adefine_enum_for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specifying the `test_framework :rspec` for shoulda-matchers#configuration solved this problem.

[shoulda-matchers#configuration](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#configuration)

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec

    with.library :active_record
    with.library :active_model
    with.library :action_controller
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Configuration Required

1. spec_helper.rb/rails_helper.rb configure block
2. type: metadata

#### spec_helper.rb/rails_helper.rb

I required the Shoulda::Matchers configuration in the spec_helper.rb (the application had not been migrated to `rails_helper.rb` - but `rails_helper.rb` is the place I would have put it if available):

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails # same as :active_record + :active_model + :active_controller
  end
end
```

#### Metadata

But, it also required the `type:` metadata before it worked:

```
This==============\/
describe User, type: :model do
  it { should define_enum_for(:status) }
end
```